# webelement selenium - how to found an element with xpath and link with onclick

Tags: javascript, selenium, selenium-webdriver, xpath

I try to get element like this :

```
webDriver.findElement(By.xpath("//a[contains(@onclick="submitData('updateShortcodeAdmin','')")]"));
```

or like this :

```
webDriver.findElement(By.xpath("//a[contains(@onclick=\"submitData(\'updateShortcodeAdmin\',\'\');")]\"));
```

or like this :

```
webDriver.findElement(By.xpath("//a[contains(@onclick=\"submitData(\'updateShortcodeAdmin\',\'\')\")]"));
```

**and got the same Error :**

```
org.openqa.selenium.InvalidSelectorException: invalid selector: Unable to locate an element with the xpath expression //a[contains(@onclick="submitData('updateShortcodeAdmin','')")] because of the following error:
SyntaxError: Failed to execute 'evaluate' on 'Document': The string '//a[contains(@onclick="submitData('updateShortcodeAdmin','')")]' is not a valid XPath expression.
```

What am I writing wrong?

Thanks !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please use the below xpath :

```
//a[contains(@onclick,'submitData('updateShortcodeAdmin')')]
```

**Explanation :**

You are using `=` in contains method, it should have been `,`

I checked in compiler that

```
webDriver.findElement(By.xpath("//a[contains(@onclick,'submitData('updateShortcodeAdmin')')]"));
```

does not show any compile error.

**PS :** Please check in the `dev tools` (Google chrome) if we have **unique** entry in `HTML DOM` or not.

**Steps to check:**

`Press F12 in Chrome` -> go to `element` section -> do a `CTRL  + F` -> then paste the `xpath` and see, if your desired `element` is getting **highlighted** with `1/1` matching node.

**Update :**

```
webDriver.findElement(By.xpath("//a[contains(@onclick,'updateShortcodeAdmin')]"));
```

Comment: webDriver.findElement(By.xpath("//a[contains(@onclick,'submitData('updateShortcodeAdmin')')]"));

I try it and got this error:

invalid selector: Unable to locate an element with the xpath expression //a[contains(@onclick,'submitData('updateShortcodeAdmin')')] because of the following error:
SyntaxError: Failed to execute 'evaluate' on 'Document': The string '//a[contains(@onclick,'submitData('updateShortcodeAdmin')')]' is not a valid XPath expression.

Comment: You are using `'`, I have given you `"`

Comment: Check the updated code above, how to check in HTMLDOM.